# This program says wrong even when it is right, also how do I make this a loop when they get it wrong?

Tags: python

I was also originally using a while loop that said if guess does not equal x run again

```
import random;
x = random.randint(1, 100);
print(x);
guess = input("Guess a number 1 to 100");
if guess == x:
     print("correct");
    sys.exit()
else:
     print("wrong");
     print("Guess a number 1 to 100");
```

Comment: Computers do what you tell them to do. If the 'program is wrong,' then your logic is incorrect.

Comment: `input` returns a string; `"50" == 50` is False.

Comment: That moment when answer `if int(guess) == x:` can fit a comment..

Comment: Please get rid of the trailing semicolons.

Answer (score 3):

This `guess = input("Guess a number 1 to 100");` will give you a string. So if you enter `4` the program will compare `'4' == 4` which is `False`.

Use :

```
guess = int(input("Guess a number 1 to 100"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing a string to an integer. So, in this case x is an integer, whereas `guess` is a string.

You can convert `guess` into a string by typecasting it into an integer.

```
guess = int(input("Guess a number 1 to 100"));
```

Before Python 3.0 , the input statement would have automatically evaluated the input to convert it into an integer ( evaluation of the input string is done ) , but in python 3.0 , a string is returned always.

> Note Change in Python 3: If you are using Python 3, please note that
>   this has changed. The input() built-in function always returns a
>   string. To convert the string to a number, either use eval(), or cast
>   the string to the desired data type with int(), float() See the
>   documentation for Python 3 built-in functions.

See more here : http://faculty.salina.k-state.edu/tim/NPstudy_guide/python/pyio.html#basic-i-o-reading-data

Comment: import random;
    import sys;
    x = random.randint(1, 100);
    #print(x);
guess = int(input("Guess a number 1 to 100"));
if guess == x:
        print("correct");
        sys.exit()
    while guess != x:
        print("wrong");
        int(input("Guess a number 1 to 100"));
        #print(x);
        if guess == x:
            print("Correct");
            sys.exit()
                        
This is my revised code but there is still a bug. When i get it wrong two or more times it will always say wrong no matter what.